# Can I use the WiFi drivers on Ubuntu on a VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, drivers, virtual-machine, windows-8.1

I have an Windows 8.1 computer that I am getting the "Limited connection" error on WiFi networks, even when I have two, three, or even four bars. After talking to support for a bit, they told me that it wasn't compatible with 8.1, yet that the drivers would be available in a few short weeks.

Since I already have it and it isn't returnable anymore I want to try to install Linux in a VM so I can temporarily use it without having a bunch of software to remove when it's ready. However, if I do so, wouldn't it still use Window 8.1's drivers since it is a VM? **Is there any way I can transfer "ownership" of the network card to Ubuntu?** I can't really install Wubi since I cannot get onto WiFi *at all.*

Comment: Is it a USB WiFi adapter?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No: PCIe x1 (Rosewill N9003PCe). I know you can do that with USB ports but internal cards... Windows may "claim" the slot first though... :/

Comment: This will depend on your hardware. If it supports VT-d (PCIe Passthrough to VM) then you may be able to use the WiFi NIC in a VM. What hardware do you have ?

Comment: @Lawrence I have a Rosewill N9003PCe WiFi card with an AMD FX 6100. MBO: ASUS M5A78L-M LX PLUS

Comment: Can't seem to find any information on whether that Motherboard supports PCIe Passthrough. Only way to find out would be to try it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot. The [VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) on PCIE Passthrough states, in its **first** line:

> When running on Linux hosts, with a recent enough kernel (at least version 2.6.31) experimental host PCI devices passthrough is available.

A number of further restrictions, even for Linux systems, are then described. Nowhere is mention made of Windows.

Sorry to have to break the bad news.

Comment: Guess I'll just have to wait. Thanks for the help!